# Rewrite an URL and also block the file extension?

Tags: apache, url, url-rewriting

Is it possible to rewrite an url and also block the file extension?.

eg: if I have

```
`http://www.example.com/search.php?...`
```

can I rewrite it to

```
`http://www.example.com/search?` ?
```

but, blocking the access to the .php file, normally I can access with both ways, with and without the file extension, but I want it to show an error page or 404 if I access with search.php.

Is it possible?.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} .*\.php
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ error404.html [R=404]
```

Comment: I can access with .php but not without it.

Comment: That's not what the rules say. Are you sure you applied them properly?

Comment: Ok, now it works, but no quite good, it blocks the file completely. with and without the extension.

Answer (score 0):

Please consider using the following config:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [L]

RewriteRule ^(.*)\.php$ error404.html [R=301,L]
```